# Why MySQL init_connect variable gets updated after rebooting?

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-5.6

After `SET GLOBAL init_connect='';` query everything works fine. However after rebooting the server or restarting the MySQL service it updates the init_connect value to some random value (OÇÿOÇÖ). Do I need to set init_connect to `''` after every reboot or is there any solution for that?

Thanks in advance,

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to find the `my.ini`, look for `init_connect`, and change it, remove it, or comment it out.

Then, run

```
net stop mysql
net start mysql
```

If the values keep getting reset anyway, you have to do the following:

Create a file called `C:\mysql_init.sql` the the contents

```
SET GLOBAL init_connect='';
```

Go back to `my.ini` and add this line

```
init_file=C:/mysql_init.sql
```

then run

```
net stop mysql
net start mysql
```

If you do not do this, you will have to run `SET GLOBAL init_connect='';` after every reboot

This is funny. I talked about this before : [Screwed up MySQL init_connect](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13435/screwed-up-mysql-init-connect/13525#13525). Based on that old post of mine, I would check what character sets you are working with.

Perhaps you can put something bogus like

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET autocommit=1'
```

and restart mysql.

Comment: still updating itself, I changed the init_connect value from the my.ini file and did net start/stop

Comment: The MySQL service is starting....
The MySQL service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: I have manually installed mysql probably it is in different directory

Comment: character-set-server=utf8

Comment: I guess the garbage showing up in `init_connect` was a protection against users who do not have `SUPER` privilege : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect

Comment: probably yes, or I have ruined something while i was upgrading from 5.1 to 5.6 (if you remember from last week lol).