# Why restoring a large sql file via SSH seems to quit partially through the process

Tags: mysql, restore, configuration

I have a large (~5GB) .sql file I am attempting to restore via SSH, it seems to quit in the middle of the restore process.

When I come back hours later after issuing the command (the file has 7 tables), there are only 5 tables and nothing is being processed.

Is there a log file I can view to see why it quit half-way through? Is there a configuration option I am probably missing? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The command I am using:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the technical details of how you are restoring (command-line args etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either the problem is with MySQL connections being killed silently, in which case please set:

```
[mysqld]
net_read_timeout = 7200
net_write_timeout = 7200
```

Defaults are extremely low (30 seconds). These params set the number of seconds waiting upon a command before aborting a connection.

Or the problem is as you suggest with your SSH. In which case use [screen](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acuy.html). If you don't know about `screen`, you are missing on a major tool. In very brief, it splits your shell, and allows you to close the terminal without breaking ongoing processes. It allows you to re-connect at another time or place, share your connection with others, and more.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to login to mysql and run the following command

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

mysqld could be busy rebuilding indexes for you table. There is no way to know otherwise.

Here is another aspect to think about: If you have TEXT or BLOB data and you have the default setting of max_allowed_packet, that could potentially kill a mass INSERT in progress

- `Sep 01, 2011` : [MySQL server has gone away obstructing import of large dumps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps/5323#5323)
- `Aug 14, 2012` : ["Mysql has gone away" heavy multiple insert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22462/mysql-has-gone-away-heavy-multiple-insert/22464#22464)

## RECOMMENDATION

Increase [**max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to 256M in /etc/my.cnf and restart mysql

## **UPDATE 2012-08-15 15:14 EDT**

If all your data is MyISAM, you should also increase the [**bulk_insert_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size) to 256M

Now, my recommendation is to add these to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=256M
bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M
```

and restart mysql

Comment: I think I found my problem- I wasn't aware once your SSH connection closes, the command will stop running. I managed to find the command 'nohup' and it seems to be working so far. I'll update with an answer if that was the problem.