# High rise in Aborted_connects on mysql slave servers

Tags: mysql

I have a **MYSQL replication** set up where I have a single master and three slave DBs. The slave DBs are load balanced behind a **Zeus** Load Balancer.

I can see on slave DB servers that the Aborted_connects are rising regularly. The same is not happening on Master DB server.

```
mysql> show status like '%Aborted_connects%';
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| Aborted_connects | 340973 |
+------------------+--------+
```

To isolate any possible php code connection related issue and or any suspicious connection, I have disconnected on of the slave DB server and run **tcpdump**. I don't see any unrecognisable connection coming in to the server except for monitoring tool and master db connection (replication).

However, I have see time to time some of the below messages on mysql error log

```
140213  9:42:17 [Warning] Aborted connection 2099906 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'gvdb' host: '10.140.10.133' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Not sure how this might help, but someone has advised on this [Fixing MySQL errors recorded in error logs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6134/fixing-mysql-errors-recorded-in-error-logs) to increase max_allowed_packet to 128MB.

Even after turning off replication, the Aborted_connects keep rising.

Comment: Well, does the username "gvdb" or the IP address "10.140.10.133" mean something?  At first glance, it sounds like this may be the load balancer doing health checks in a somewhat ungraceful fashion.

Comment: Yes, others have also posted similar issues here http://forums.webyog.com/index.php?showtopic=6999. the IP 10.140.10.133 ip is load balancer related. We use Zeus Load Balancer. Th MySQL Load balancer pool was there for a long time. I used get this sort of error messages once in a while but now it's more frequent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to solve Aborted_Connects problem**

1) Increase the `wait_timeout` variable value in `[my.cnf]`

2) Set the `log-warnings` variable to greater than 1. This will start logging the aborted connections in the mysql error log file once you identified and fixed the problem you can set it back to 1 again.

Also, You can have a look at this forum discussion which is relevant to Load balancer which checks database health every second
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?144,194590,194590#msg-194590

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, as discussed this issue is caused by the load balancer's health check rather than any hack attempt. I will have to change the load balancer's settings so it makes a proper connection.